# Exception - nullpointer exception. How do i fix it?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, nullpointerexception, observer-pattern

The below program throws an exception for the action performed method and a whole bunch of other actions. It doesn't show any error. But gives a null pointer exception. Can anyone help on this? I'm trying to implement this in model view controller and observer patterns

Below is the Exception :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Controller.actionPerformed(Controller.java:9)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2012)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2335)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:404)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:253)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6268)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6033)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2045)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4629)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2103)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4455)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4633)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4297)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4227)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2089)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2517)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4455)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:649)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:96)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:608)
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:606)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:105)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:116)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:622)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:620)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:105)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:619)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:275)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:200)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:190)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:185)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:177)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
```

Comment: Where is the exception? You've posted a lot of code, but not given us the crucial stack trace. You've also posted far more code than I suspect you really need to demonstrate the problem, and it's poorly formatted...

Comment: First properly format Your question so that the reader can pick your code easily

Comment: also your frame in your actionlistener is null, i think thats why you get the nullpointer

Comment: Your `getInstance()` method never initialize `INSTANCE` variable always creating new `ProductCatalog` instances

Answer (score 2):

You never set the `frame` attribute of the `Controller` class.

First add a constructor to the `Controller` class.

```
public Controller(SaleFrame frame) {
    this.frame = frame;
}
```

Then pass the value in the `SaleFrame`

```
private Controller controller1 = new Controller(this);
```

Also you need to add following line

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

to exit your application when `JFrame` get closed.

Comment: Thanks a tonn. That solves the problem . I'm i using the observer and mvc pattern in the right way?

Comment: Honestly you are not. But please ask another question focusing on the design patterns. Also your code looks not complete, so remove or use unused parts.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't initialised `frame` in your Controller class. You could change the constructor for your Controller class so that it accepts and initialises a reference to your SaleFrame.

```
public Controller(SaleFrame frame)
{
    this.frame = frame;
}
```

And then you can invoke this constructor like so in the SaleFrame class.

```
private Controller controller1= new Controller(this);
```

Comment: Thanks that solves the problem . I'm i using the observer and mvc pattern in the right way?

Comment: I'm probably not the best person to ask about design patterns. You might be better off asking at [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)